# c# | Timer to check a button click

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a game where you have to click on a button, and to put it 
simply, all i want is a timer to check if a button was pressed in the last 10 seconds. if so, it needs to display a message that the game was over, else - it will reset the count of the seconds.
can anyone help me please?
**code:**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Pointer
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        //Variables
        int count = 0; //Count The Score
        bool RandomColorEnabled = true;
        bool GameStarted = false;
        int OverCount = 0;        

        //Dialogs
        ColorDialog clg = new ColorDialog();        

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void Pointer_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Interval
            if (count % 20 == 0)
            {
                if (Movement.Interval >= 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Movement.Interval -= 900;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Movement.Interval = 100;
                    }
                }                
            }

            //StartingText
            StartingText.Enabled = false;
            StartingText.Visible = false;

            //Creates the all-mighty random that does pretty much everything
            Random rnd = new Random();

            //Checks if the user wants a random color each time.
            if (RandomColorEnabled)
            {
                int R = rnd.Next(0, 240);
                int G = rnd.Next(0, 240);
                int B = rnd.Next(0, 240);
                Pointer.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(R, G, B);
            }

            if (GameStarted)
            {
                //Score
                count++;
            Score.Text = "Score: " + count;
            }

            GameStarted = true;

            //No Focus
            this.Focus();

        }


        //Menu Strip Shit Here:

        private void Reset_All_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Restart();
        }

        private void Reset_Score_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count = 0;
            Score.Text = "Score: " + count;
        }

        private void Reset_Pointer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GameStarted = false;
            StartingText.Enabled = true;
            StartingText.Visible = true;
            Reset_Score.PerformClick();
            Movement.Interval = 10000;
            Pointer.Location = new Point(213, 189);
        }

        private void CustomColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RandomColorEnabled = false;
            clg.FullOpen = true;
            clg.ShowDialog();
            if (clg.Color.R < 240 && clg.Color.G < 240 && clg.Color.B < 240)
            {
                Pointer.BackColor = clg.Color;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, Please Pick A Diffrent Color.");
            }
        }

        private void RandomColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RandomColorEnabled = true;
        }

        private void Menu_About_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This Program Was Created By Itay Habani ©","~About~",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        private void Menu_Help_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click the pointer to earn points.\nTo pick your own color, go to:\nSettings -> Pointer Color -> Custom", "-HELP-", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        }

        private void Movement_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            //Placement  
            if (GameStarted)
            {
                int x = rnd.Next(50, 400);
                int y = rnd.Next(50, 400);
                Pointer.Location = new Point(x, y);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Is all of this code relevant to your problem? Can you provide the minimal code needed to show your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm could be the following:

- declare `bool` variable `isClicked` and set it to `false`
- when button is clicked:

  - set `isClicked` to true
  - start the [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Timers.Timer(v=vs.110).aspx), set its `Interval` to 10 seconds and attach to     `Elapsed` event a callback which stops the timer and sets `isClicked` to false

Comment: I am not familiar with the Elapsed event. Can you please explain how it works? (a piece of code will be helpful aswell)

Comment: Did you open and read MSDN article on Timer class I posted in the answer? There are also examples. Try it yourself first, that's the best way to learn. If you don't understand something, then ask here some specific question.